# Как найти сумму квадратов чисел между a и b включительно?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика, циклы

> Даны числа a и b. Найдите сумму квадратов чисел между a и b включительно. Неизвестно, какое из чисел a или b больше.

Моё решение:

```
function testCycle(a, b) {
    var x;
    if (a <=b){
        for (var i = a; i <= b; i++ ){
            x+= Math.pow (i++);
        }
    }else if (b <a){
        for (var i = b; i <= a; i++ ){
            x+= Math.pow (i++);
        }
    }
        
    return x;
}
```

Что с ним не так?

Answer (score 5):

Просто если `a>b`, поменяйте их местами.

Потом вычислите

```
(a*(-1 + (3 - 2*a)*a) + b*(1 + b)*(1 + 2*b))/6
```

Это и есть искомый результат...

Что-то вроде (я не спец в JS)

```
function testCycle(a, b) 
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        var x = a;
        a = b;
        b = x;
    }
 
    return (a*(-1 + (3 - 2*a)*a) + b*(1 + b)*(1 + 2*b))/6;
}
```

P.S. Выкладки для Grundy:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но, честно говоря, ясности не прибавило.

Comment: Сумма квадратов - формула давно известная, наверное, класс 8-9.... Зачем считать циклы, если есть точная, ясная формула?

Comment: а почему часть `a` какая-то странная? Она разве не должна быть такой же как и с `b`, только с минусом? То есть как-то так: `- ((a-1)(1 + a-1)(1+2*(a-1)))`, если внутри скобок сложить у меня получилось: `-(a * (a-1) * (2a - 1))`

Comment: @Grundy Потому что включительно. Пусть f(a) - сумма квадратов от 0 до a включительно. Чему будет равна сумма квадратов от a до b включительно? f(b)-f(a)? А вот фигушки :)

Comment: @Harry, `f(b) - f(a-1)` же? У меня в комментарии так я считал.

Comment: @Grundy Именно. Я уж не помню, почему у меня такая именно запись оказалась — может, спешил, может, еще почему-то, но она, хоть и ужасно некрасивая (признаю!), но математически верна. См. выкладки в дополненном ответе.

Comment: @Harry, ага, так и думал что раскрытие скобок поможет, но что-то не осилил :)

Comment: Для вычислений я бы использовал запись для схемы Горнера (как для `a` в ответе) - `(a*(-1+(3-2*a)*a)+b*(1+b*(3+2*b)))/6` - так оно и почти симметрично, кстати. ЗЫ: посчитал, а количество умножений-сложений-делений то же самое. Так что кроме красоты ничего такая запись не дает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот это решение отработало у меня

```
var x=0;
var max = Math.max (a,b);
    var min = Math.min (a,b);
    for (i = min; i <=max; i++) {
        x+= i*i;
```

Comment: Осталось посчитать для диапазона в эдак несколько миллионов и сравнить время работы с вычислением по готовой формуле :)

Answer (score 1):

[Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) - принимает **два** параметра

1. основание
2. степень

В коде в вопросе передается только один: `Math.pow (i++)`

Также, из-за лишнего `i++`, пропускается каждый второй шаг цикла.

Таким образом, для решения достаточно заменить вызов на

```
Math.pow(i, 2)
```